# Create an ESRI Shapefile from WKT with OGR

Tags: gdal, ogr, well-known-text, python-3

I want to create an `ESRI Shapefile` layer from a `CSV` file. In my `CSV` I have several attributes (text, numeric) and geometry in `WKT` style. I have a problem with the geometry field wich is truncated to a string field (254 characters), because I don't know how to declare it.

How to create `ESRI Shapefile` geometric data from `WKT` with `ogr` ? 
`ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt()` isn't the good way ?

Maybe with [string formatting operators](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/formatting.html) ?

CSV source file:

```
serialnumber;name;objectnumber;city;geom
034002002;Peter;1;34086;POLYGON ((676923.736 6265215.412,676954.294 ... )) 
034002003;John;2;34284;POLYGON ((678870.753 6264475.605,678867.203 ... )) 
034002004;Steeve;3;34086;POLYGON ((678001.823 6264195.123,677975.609 ... ))
```

I found [this method](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#create-a-new-shapefile-and-add-data) wich explain how to parse a delimited `CSV` file to create an `ESRI Shapefile`. I'm using Python 3.7.4 and GDAL 2.3.3.

Python script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
import osgeo.ogr as ogr
import osgeo.osr as osr
import csv
import os
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'] + r'\Library\share\gdal'
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'] + r'\Library\share'

myInput = 'input.csv'

with open(myInput, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')

    # set up the shapefile driver
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

    # create the data source
    data_source = driver.CreateDataSource("output.shp")

    # create the spatial reference
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromEPSG(2154)

    # create the layer
    layer = data_source.CreateLayer("output", srs, ogr.wkbPolygon)

    # Add the fields we're interested in
    field_serialnumber = ogr.FieldDefn("serialnumber", ogr.OFTString)
    field_serialnumber.SetWidth(9)
    layer.CreateField(field_serialnumber)
    field_name = ogr.FieldDefn("name", ogr.OFTString)
    field_name.SetWidth(50)
    layer.CreateField(field_name)
    layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("objectnumber", ogr.OFTInteger))
    field_city = ogr.FieldDefn("city", ogr.OFTString)
    field_city.SetWidth(5)
    layer.CreateField(field_city)
    layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("geom"))

    # Process the text file and add the attributes and features to the shapefile
    for row in reader:
        # create the feature
        feature = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
        # Set the attributes using the values from the delimited text file
        feature.SetField("serialnumber", row['serialnumber'])
        feature.SetField("name", row['name'])
        feature.SetField("objectnumber", row['objectnumber'])
        feature.SetField("city", row['city'])
        feature.SetField("geom", row['geom'])

        # create the WKB for the feature using Python string formatting
        wkt = (row['geom'])
        polygon = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)

        # Set the feature geometry using the point
        feature.SetGeometry(polygon)

        # Create the feature in the layer (shapefile)
        layer.CreateFeature(feature)

        # Dereference the feature
        feature = None

        # Save and close the data source
        data_source = None
```

PS: `QGIS` is able to translate my `CSV` file to a layer when I import it as delimited source layer, so i'm sure this data is valid.

Comment: So is your problem with CSV DictReader? may be just read the lines from the file directly and split on `;`?

Comment: I need `csv.DictReader` to access to my ordered fields and map them with `feature.SetField`, no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it! It was an identation problem with the last instruction which save and close data source, it must be outside the `for` loop. I also removed my geom field in the `ESRI Shapefile`, I don't need it. A full answer for @Ian Turton : I'm using `DictReader` to access to my fields by their names, which is an easier way than indexes (if I understand well).

Here is a correct syntax :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
import osgeo.ogr as ogr
import osgeo.osr as osr
import csv
import os
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'] + r'\Library\share\gdal'
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'] + r'\Library\share'

myInput = 'input.csv'

with open(myInput, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')

    # set up the shapefile driver
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

    # create the data source
    data_source = driver.CreateDataSource("output.shp")

    # create the spatial reference
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromEPSG(2154)

    # create the layer
    layer = data_source.CreateLayer("output", srs, ogr.wkbPolygon)

    # Add the fields we're interested in
    field_serialnumber = ogr.FieldDefn("serialnumber", ogr.OFTString)
    field_serialnumber.SetWidth(9)
    layer.CreateField(field_serialnumber)
    field_name = ogr.FieldDefn("name", ogr.OFTString)
    field_name.SetWidth(50)
    layer.CreateField(field_name)
    layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn("objectnumber", ogr.OFTInteger))
    field_city = ogr.FieldDefn("city", ogr.OFTString)
    field_city.SetWidth(5)
    layer.CreateField(field_city)        

    # Process the text file and add the attributes and features to the shapefile
    for row in reader:
        # create the feature
        feature = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
        # Set the attributes using the values from the delimited text file
        feature.SetField("serialnumber", row['serialnumber'])
        feature.SetField("name", row['name'])
        feature.SetField("objectnumber", row['objectnumber'])
        feature.SetField("city", row['city'])

        # create the WKT for the feature using Python string formatting
        wkt = (row['geom'])
        polygon = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)

        # Set the feature geometry using the point
        feature.SetGeometry(polygon)

        # Create the feature in the layer (shapefile)
        layer.CreateFeature(feature)

        # Dereference the feature
        feature = None

    # Save and close the data source
    data_source = None
```